# History.JS pass var to above function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the var loadurl to the function above. How can i achieve this? (the code below is my function and i want to pass the id to the above code. Any help is appreciated.

$(function() {

```
// Prepare
var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
if ( !History.enabled ) {
     // History.js is disabled for this browser.
     // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
    return false;
}

// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState();



    console.log(loadurl);
    $('#test').load(loadurl);
    /* Instead of the line above, you could run the code below if the url returns the whole page instead of just the content (assuming it has a `#content`):
    $.get(State.url, function(response) {
        $('#content').html($(response).find('#content').html()); });
    */
    });


// Capture all the links to push their url to the history stack and trigger the StateChange Event
$('a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var loadurl = $(this).attr('id');



    History.pushState(loadurl, $(this).text(), $(this).attr('onclick'));
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global variable at the top of the page, assign it a value within one of your functions, and then use it in another function.